# Tengo un error en mi código - count() parameter

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario en mi código que sirve para editar una tabla de la base de datos. El problema es que estoy intentando incluir el fichero erros.php que sirve para que, cuando al editar en el formulario, el usuario o el email se devuelvan vacíos, mande un mensaje de error.

Ya había incluido antes el fichero erros.php en varios formularios  antes y nunca me había dado problemas pero ahora no se porqué me está dando error. Alguien me puede ayudar a resolver el error? Gracias.

Este es el warning que aparece siempre que incluyo erros.php en el formulario de index.php:

```
 Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on line …
```

Donde la línea está en **erros.php**: `<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>`

Este es mi código:

**Index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" <?php echo $style;?>>
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?> //Al incluir erros.php me da error
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Correo</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <?php if ($update == true): ?>
            <button class="btn" type="submit" name="update">Editar</button>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
include('Conexion.php');

$username = "";
$email = "";
$errors = array();
$id = 0;
$update = false;

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "error"); }
if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "error"); }

    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET username='$username', email='$email' WHERE id=$id");
}else {
    $_SESSION['errors_edit'] = $errors;
}
header("Location: index.php ");
?>
```

**errors.php**

```
<?php
/*$errors = [];*/
if (isset($_SESSION["errors_reg"])) {
    $errors = $_SESSION["errors_reg"];
    $_SESSION["errors_reg"] = null;
}
?>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["errors_student"])) {
    $errors = $_SESSION["errors_student"];
    $_SESSION["errors_student"] = null;
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["errors_edit"])) {
    $errors = $_SESSION["errors_student"];
    $_SESSION["errors_student"] = null;
}
?>

<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
    <div class="error">
        <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
            <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php  endif ?>
<?php
$errors = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se trata de un warning que ocurre cuando llamas a la funcion `count` sin un valor definido. Sucede sobretodo a partir de php 7.0 (o 7.1, no recuerdo ahora mismo). Esto puede estar ocurriendote porque en tu formulario no hay errores, y cuando llegas a la linea del count, `$errors` no esta definido.

Al principio del codigo tienes comentado $errors:

```
<?php
/*$errors = [];*/
if (isset($_SESSION["errors_reg"])) {
```

descomentalo:

```
<?php
$errors = [];
if (isset($_SESSION["errors_reg"])) {
```

y no deberia darte problemas, cuando el formulario sea correcto.

Por otra parte, tienes esto en el codigo:

```
$errors = $_SESSION["errors_reg"];
```

esto no seria correcto, ya que luego vas a `contar` los elementos de $errors, y ahi estas asignando una cadena. Lo correcto seria que en cada caso hicieras:

```
$errors[] = $_SESSION["errors_reg"];
```

es decir, añadir el error en caso de suceder.